# use both PUT and POST methods from same API using FastAPI

Tags: python, post, fastapi, put

I'm about to create an API using FastApi wherein I have to search for '*user_name*' in db. If '*user_name*' exists then I have to update the *user_details*. If the '*user_name*' doesn't exist, then I have to create entry for the user.
In this case, I think both **PUT** and **POST** methods need to be applied for the same API endpoint. Is this possible? can anyone brief me how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You just need to use different decorator for the same path.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()


@app.put("/")
async def put_root():
    return {"message": "Hello World from put"}

@app.post("/")
async def post_root():
    return {"message": "Hello World from post"}
```

the code is oversimplify but it shows the concept.

Comment: If you find it useful please accept the answer ;).